# jQuery show up two buttons from selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, html-select

I have this code and it works fine but not perfect. I don't know how to show up both buttons when I select options "two" and "three".

My code also seems too difficult, is a chance to write my code effectively or not? Thanks a lot.

```js
function display() {
  var selectBoxValues = $("#selectbox").val() || [];

  if (selectBoxValues == '2') {
    $('.select2').removeAttr('hidden', 'hidden');
  }
  if (selectBoxValues != '2') {
    $(".select2").attr('hidden', 'hidden');
  }
  if (selectBoxValues == '3') {
    $('.select3').removeAttr('hidden', 'hidden');
  }
  if (selectBoxValues != '3') {
    $(".select3").attr('hidden', 'hidden');
  }
}

$("#selectbox").change(display);
display();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectbox" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>

<input hidden="hidden" type="button" class="button select2" value='Button 2' id="button">

<input hidden="hidden" type="button" class="button select3" value='Button 3' id="button">
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hoa849p8/)

Comment: You can't select 2 options in a `<select>`, use other `<input>` types with multiple choices.

Comment: @AymDev you can when you add the `multiple` attribute, as the OP has

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan wow you got me ! I'll remember that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the array in multiple selection and simply code as follows

```
 function display() {
   var selectBoxValues = $( "#selectbox" ).val() || [];
   $(".button").attr('hidden','hidden'); //add hidden to all element
   selectBoxValues.forEach(function(e){
     $('.select'+e).removeAttr('hidden','hidden'); //remove hidden for selected elements
   })

 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hoa849p8/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function display() {
  var selectBoxValues = $( "#selectbox" ).val() || [];
  if (selectBoxValues.indexOf('2')>-1) {
    $('.select2').removeAttr('hidden','hidden');
  }
  if (selectBoxValues.indexOf('2') == -1) {
    $(".select2").attr('hidden','hidden');
  }
  if (selectBoxValues.indexOf('3')>-1) {
    $('.select3').removeAttr('hidden','hidden');
  }
  if (selectBoxValues.indexOf('3')==-1) {
    $(".select3").attr('hidden','hidden');
  }
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hoa849p8/3/)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is that the `val()` returned from the multiple select is an array, so by comparing an array to a string you will encounter issues when multiple options are selected.

To fix this you can use the `indexOf()` method to find the specific value in the array and show the relevant button using `toggle()`. Also note I've never seen `hidden` used as an attribute on an `input` element, and frankly I'm more amazed it works. I'd suggest you use CSS to hide/show the element instead. Finally, you should make the `id` attributes unique too, as sharing them between the buttons is invalid.  Try this:

```js
function display() {
  var selectBoxValues = $("#selectbox").val() || [];  
  $('.select2').toggle(selectBoxValues.indexOf('2') != -1);
  $('.select3').toggle(selectBoxValues.indexOf('3') != -1);
}

$("#selectbox").change(display).change();
```

```css
.button { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectbox" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>

<input type="button" class="button select2" value="Button 2" id="button1">
<input type="button" class="button select3" value="Button 3" id="button2">
```

Answer (score 1):

Thre problem with the code is `selectBoxValues` contains array of selected elements and we are comparing it only with first element. So we have to disable all the buttons first loop through array and remove hidden wherever necessary.

Here is the fiddle for it. http://jsfiddle.net/hoa849p8/4/

JS code is as below :

```
function display() {
  var selectBoxValues = $( "#selectbox" ).val() || [];
  console.log(selectBoxValues);
  $('.button').attr('hidden','hidden');
  $(selectBoxValues).each(function(i,item){
    $('.select'+item).removeAttr('hidden');
  });
}

$( "#selectbox" ).change( display );
display();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following as a little refactoring

http://jsfiddle.net/hoa849p8/2/

**HTML**

stays as yours

**SCRIPT**

```
function display() {
    var selectBoxValues = $( "#selectbox" ).val() || [];
    var buttons = $(".button");
    buttons.attr("hidden", "hidden");

    if (selectBoxValues == '2') {
        $('.select2').removeAttr('hidden','hidden');
    }

    if (selectBoxValues == '3') {
        $('.select3').removeAttr('hidden','hidden');
    }
}
$( "#selectbox" ).change( display );
```